# Printing a # in c

Tags: c

From my program, I am trying to execute a command using popen` which contains:

```
sprintf(buff, "echo -n cd %s; ls | awk -F'.' '{print $2"."$3"."$4'#'$5}'"
```

But compiler says 'stray # in program'.

How to print `"#"` in C ?

Comment: How to store # under the char array ?

Comment: Put it inside of quotation marks.

Comment: Let me guess. It's not the "#" but you forgot to escape the inner quotes

Comment: And, what does any of this have to do with C, C++, Linux or C++11.  This is clearly an Awk question

Comment: @DavidHoelzer op mentioned `popen()` so C seems to be OK

Comment: you people really misunderstood............

Comment: I see zero C++ code anywhere, never mind C code.  He's simply failed to escape quotation marks.

Comment: this is the statement : sprintf(buff, "echo -n cd %s; ls |  awk -F'.' '{print $2"."$3"."$4'#'$5}'"

Comment: Get a good editor with syntax highlighting, and error like these should be easy to see.

Comment: This is not an awk question

Comment: No. The code goes in the question, *not* in a comment.

Comment: Deleting the awk tag since as the OP correctly states `This is not an awk question` (which of course begs the question why add that tag in the first place but lets consider that rhetorical...).

Comment: This happens ........ because you people are in hurry ...so much

Comment: @enamel OK, riddle me this: why did cause *our* hurry the sloppiness of the question?

Answer (score 1):

Your `#` needs to be between quotation marks (`"`). If you want to have quotation marks as characters in a string you need to escape them with `\` (e.g. `"\""`).

So the string should be `"echo -n cd %s; ls | awk -F'.' '{print $2\".\"$3\".\"$4\"#\"$5}'"`.

Comment: It sounds like Enamel is a beginner with C programming. You should probably provide the entire statement for him.